# Stored procedure to search a keyword in all the tables of database

Tags: database, search, stored-procedures

I'm working on a database, where I got a situation to search for a keyword (that may be either name or address or city etc). And now I need to create a Stored Procedure to make search in all the tables of the database..!!

Can anybody help me out of this plz..!!

Comment: You are going to have to prove *a lot* more information. For example, what kind of database? What programming language are you using? Provide us some code if you can.

Answer (score 0):

No database has built-in support for such a requirement. So, you have to develop your own solution depending on the environment and criteria.

Now, a general solution would be to create a procedure that iterates over all the columns in all the tables and finds the matching columns. This usually implies a considerable performance cost depending on the size of your database and must be either avoided or performance-checked carefully. Techniques such as column type checking could be used to reduce the search space and avoid unnecessary costs.

Depending on your database type, other solutions may be available. For example, if your database is Oracle, I found the technique given [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=3360446#3360446) a useful one. Also, most widely used databases, including Oracle, support full text search capabilities which offer efficient searching of patterns inside text columns. You should consult your database manual to find an efficient way to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

Here I go with answer,

You have to select the columns u desired to perform search functionality,

Then start something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 on TABLE2.a = TABLE1.a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 on TABLE3.a = TABLE1.a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE4 on TABLE4.a = TABLE3.a

WHERE TABLE1.a LIKE '%'. Keyword . '%' OR
      TABLE2.b LIKE '%'. Keyword . '%' OR
      TABLE3.a LIKE '%'. Keyword . '%' OR
      TABLE4.c LIKE '%'. Keyword . '%' OR
      TABLE1.b LIKE '%'. Keyword . '%'
```

etc...

This is one of the basic ways, However v will have much more Efficient ways..

might help someone..